# React native: plug-in for audio recorder on Android

Tags: android, react-native, audio-recording, android-audiorecord, native-module

Is there any available plugin for recording audio? 
Searching on google but no luck.

Thanks,
Huy

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.